# Como dar estilos a una barra de scroll en Qt (Qss)

Tags: qt, pyqt

estoy practicando un poco en Qss para un proyecto que debo llevar a cabo y me topo con varios problemas. Esto leyendo la documentación de Qt en cuanto a propiedades de estilos pero veo a mi parecer que es algo limitado ya que no toma muchas posibilidades de edición.

Imagen link: http://prntscr.com/m9kzzj

Actualmente tengo esta barra vertical que es un ScrollBar estoy tratando de que los bordes sean completamente redondos.

Apliqué `border-radius:80px;` como lo haría en Css para que fuera completamente redondo en varias dimensiones.

Sin embargo no sirvio de nada por lo que opté por utilizar el metodo de la documentación que dice:

```
QScrollBar {
   border-with: 1px; //Defiene una linea en el borde.
   border-style: solid; // Define el estilo del borde yo lo puse en solido.
   border-radius: 80px; // Yo lo puse en 80px para que tomara eso en varias dimensiones.
}
```

Entonces pienso que se puede cambiar la barra por alguna imagen en SVG ya que de esa forma tendría los bordes pre-definidos.

---

El otro problema sería con el fondo de la misma barra, este tiene como un aspecto poco agradable visualmente intenté modificarlo con varias propiedades pero niguna tuvo éxito.

En realidad lo que hice fue aplicar un background:#000; y si cambio pero se mantuvo la textura punteada.

Espero haberme explicado bien se que Qt está un poco descontinuado pero no creo que sea mala idea intentar aprender a manejarlo quizás toque en algún proyecto futuro ;) Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qt Descontinuado? ¿por qué señalas eso?

Comment: @eyllanesc cierto mi error no es descontinuado en realidad es muy actual jejeje

Comment: cambia `border-with` a `border-width`